# Odoo installed on Docker

Tags: docker, odoo, devops

I have Odoo's enterprise addons and i 'm trying to start a container using this addons and my own custom addons. Can someone help me how to add enterprise addons. for now, i've add path of my custom addons and it work but i don't know how to do with enterprise addons.
Thanks for reply

Answer (score 2):

First of all you've to search for the **`config`** file of your installed odoo. In your docker the running OS is **`linux`** then your config file may be in **`/etc`**

Then add your enterprise addons path in your config file like following.

```
addons_path = /opt/odoo13/odoo/enterprise/addons
```

In docker if your running OS is **`windows`** then your config file may be in **`C:\Program File (x86)\Odoo12.0\server\odoo.conf`**

If you want to add two path one for custom addons and second is for enterprise addons then try this in your config file.

```
addons_path = /opt/odoo13/odoo/enterprise/addons, /opt/odoo13/odoo/custom_addons
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first update the **addons_path** in the **`config`** file as explained by [Adam Strauss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11796003/adam-strauss), then, depending on the usage of docker-compose or docker you will type different commands but **the point is to mount the two addons' volumes**, the first for the enterprise's version addons and the second for the custom addons.

For **docker-compose**, the **`docker-compose.yml`** should mount both addons directories as stated in the config file. Make sure to make the config file match the container filesystem and not the host file system. Find below an example of what it will look like.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:12.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./odoo/enterprise/addons:/opt/odoo13/addons
      - ./odoo/custom_addons:/opt/odoo13/custom_addons
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
```

All details are well explained [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo).